# Parsing an arraylist of lat/lon to obtain western most latitude

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called Coordinate it contains two attributes - latitude and longitude. I add this to an ArrayList. Now I want to obtain the western most coordinate of this ArrayList. I want an efficient  algorithm(as I have 6000) coordinate classes.

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(listOfCoordinates, new Comparator<Coordinate>() { @override public int compare(Coordinate c1, Coordinate c2) {return ${INSERT CUSTOM COMPARE HERE}}});`

Comment: In java8, ArrayList now have sort method : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: @phtrivier I was tilting towards the Custom Comparator approach but this Collections.sort API is new to me. Need to take a look at it.

Comment: For sorting algo : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to obtain the western most, then there is no reason to sort the list.

```
Coord mostWest = Coord.newAtMaximumEast();
for(Coord coord : listOfCoordinates)
   if(coord.isFurtherWest(mostWest))
     mostWest = coord;
```

A less readable version might be:

```
Coord mostWest = null;
for(Coord coord : listOfCoordinates)
   if(mostWest == null || coord.getLong() < mostWest.getLong())
     mostWest = coord;
```

This is O(*n*) complexity, all sorting algorithms are more complex, with the most efficient still being O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: what does newAtMaximumEast() do ? Is it just a constructor ?

Comment: Creates a new coordinate at the farthest east possible.

Comment: But I don't know what the farthest east coord is either.

Comment: +1 If you need the maximum or minimum of a list, you should not sort. The complexity of a sort is always greater than O(n) and the complexity of just going over the loop to find maximum or minimum is O(n).

Comment: I have reworded my question to reflect your answer. Does it pass?

Comment: Yes, that's more consistent.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8 you can use functional style:

```
Collections.sort(coordinateList, (c1, c2) -> c1.getLon().compareTo(c2.getLon()));
```

Comment: Good but Longitude represents East/West, not Latitude.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom Comparator and use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).